# core data database values life cycle

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Am developing an application using core data. Every time I delete the application from the emulator all the data that was inserted using core data is deleted. does this mean when i publish my application my data base will be empty? I want the data base to have values when i publish it or install it to anther device.

Comment: Apple Documentation: [How do I initialize a store with default data?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFAQ.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001802-SW5)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a database and package it inside your application bundle for distribution.  Then, whenever your application starts up, before using any data it can check to see if there's a copy of the database in the working directory.  If not, it should copy the packaged one.

Comment: how do you package the core data database the is already there ?

Comment: Copy it into your project and make sure it's included in the "Copy Bundle Resources" part of your target's "Build Phases".

Comment: what file exactly do i copy to the "copy Bundle Resources" to ensure the the data base is included?